# Xpath improvement

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath

```
<document>
<html class=" js " lang="en" style="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="head">
<body class="modern operational">
<div class="row btm16">
<div class="col-xs-30">
<label>Adjust To </label>
</div>
<span id="pb33352:eastFieldForm:j_idt2056:adjInputTextPanel">
<input id="pb33352:eastFieldForm:j_idt2056:newValueNumber" class="form-control" type="text"  maxlength="11" name="pb33352:eastFieldForm:j_idt2056:newValueNumber"/>
<span>
<span id="pb33352:eastFieldForm:j_idt2056:adjustToUnit"/>
</span>
</span>
<div class="col-md-40"/>
<span id="pb33352:eastFieldForm:j_idt2056:errorMessages"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</document>
```

I have this above simple page having a label and a text box. I want to enter text into the text box.

The `XPATH` that will help me is `//*[contains(text(),normalize-space('Adjust To'))]//..//..//*[self::input]`.

With the above solution I am not happy with using of multiple `//..` in the middle.
Is there a better way to get this `XPATH`.

Please note I need to find `xpath` by finding text "Adjust To"

Comment: Indeed `//..` is a very strange thing to write. It means `/descendant-or-self::node()/parent::node()`, i.e. it's the union of your own parent node, plus all your non-leaf descendants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [`following` axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following):

```
//label[normalize-space(.) = 'Adjust To']/following::input
```

Alternatively, I think using the "adjInputTextPanel" part of the `id` is also a good enough locator:

```
//span[contains(@id, 'adjInputTextPanel')]/input
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try by using [preceding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding) axes as below :-

```
//input[preceding::label[normalize-space(.) = 'Adjust To']]
```

Comment: The OP specifically notes _"I need to find xpath by finding text "Adjust To""_

Comment: @Slanec sorry...I didn't  see...now i have updated...:)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys for the above solution and it helps.

I was also trying ways from my end as well and found below one to be helpful.

```
//label[contains(.,'Adjust To')]/following::input[1]
```